# Python - Subclass TypeError: takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) while it should take 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a subclass from a parent class as shown below:

In ParentClass.py:

```
class ParentClass(Object):
    def __init__(self, reg, wr=None, rd=None):
        self.register = reg
        self.wr=wr
        self.rd=rd

    def other_function(self):
        ...
```

In ChildClass.py:

```
import ParentClass

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, reg, wr, rd):
        super().__init__(reg, wr, rd)    

    def other_function(self):
        override parent class...
```

My main purpose is to override the other_function here. However, I get the following error when running the code:

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

That error does not make any sense to me because I have passed 3 arguments and parent class also takes 3 arguments. Where is the 2 come from? And what is wrong with my code here?

Thanks

Comment: Let me guess, you did `import ParentClass` in `ChildClass.py`. (If not, please post a [mcve].)

Comment: Hi, yes, you are right. I import that. Should I not to do that? If I did not do that, it complain: the name ParentClass is not defined

Comment: You should import it correctly: `from ParentClass import ParentClass`. If you do `import ParentClass`, then `ParentClass` refers to the _module_ instead of your class.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. It solves my problem!! Now I understand the proper way to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ParentClass` refers to the wrong thing. After you do `import ParentClass`, `ParentClass` is a *module*, not a *class*:

```
import ParentClass

print(ParentClass)
# output: <module 'ParentClass' from 'C:\foo\ParentClass.py'>
```

---

You can either import the `ParentClass` class directly into your namespace:

```
from ParentClass import ParentClass

# now it's as expected:
print(ParentClass)
# output: <class ParentClass.ParentClass>
```

Or leave the import as is, and access the class through the imported module:

```
import ParentClass

class ChildClass(ParentClass.ParentClass):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In ChildClass.py, I should do

```
from ParentClass import ParentClass
```

That will properly import ParentClass and not its module